# unable to build boost file from cmake

Tags: cmake, boost

Boost is installed in the system path so I am able to compile the `main.cpp` file with command

```
g++ main.cpp -lboost_filesystem
```

But when I try to build the file with CMake, I get the error.

My main.cpp file is like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main() {
    namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

    fs::path currentPath = fs::current_path();
    std::cout << "Current Path: " << currentPath << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

this file runs fine with command

```
g++ main.cpp-o main -lboost_filesystem
```

but when I tries to build this file with CMake with code

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(BoostExample)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE Boost::filesystem)
```

I get error like

```
boost/filesystem.hpp: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```